# How to solve the issue of "undefined: math.Round" while installing app of go using docker

Tags: docker, go

I make golang api's code and I have imported some packages in it like `math`. But while building an image by running the `sudo docker build -t users/micro .` Then at one step it will give me the error.

Error

```
 Step 6/8 : RUN go install
 ---> Running in 454784b3ceef
 # bkapiv/users/utils
 utils/CommonFunctions.go:189:9: undefined: math.Round
```

Dockerfile

```
# Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang:1.9.6


WORKDIR /go/src/bkapiv/users

# Copy the local package files to the container's workspace.
ADD . /go/src/bkapiv/users

# Build the outyet command inside the container.
# (You may fetch or manage dependencies here,
# either manually or with a tool like "godep".)
RUN cd /go/src
RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
RUN go install

# Run the outyet command by default when the container starts.
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/users

# Document that the service listens on port 8080.
EXPOSE 8080
```

Imported packages are

```
package utils

import (
 "bytes"
 "fmt"
 "math"
 "math/rand"
 "os/exec"
 "reflect"
 "sort"
 "strconv"
 "time"
)

 187 func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
 188        // for this line it will giving me the error 
 189    return math.Round(x/unit) * unit
 190 }
```

How I will resolve my error

Answer (score 8):

The function `Round()` from the `math` package was only introduced in Go 1.10 ([see the release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#math)). Your Dockerfile uses an older 1.9.6 version, so you will have to upgrade.